Blender 4.2 EEVEE strange red dots appearing on the edge of the object surface
When using Blender 4.2EEVEE, strange red dots will appear on the edges of some models. These red dots will gradually appear and flicker when the view is zoomed in on the model. 

Hello, maybe tweak the Clip Start and End values in the N panel > View?

I tried it, but the problem still exists. This problem has nothing to do with the view.

I found that most of the models that cause this problem are "skinned" human models, and I don't understand why this happens.

It could look like an issue with alpha straight/premultiplied, are you doing any shape or form of compositing, i.e. playing with transparency, combining images or layers, ... ?

I rarely combining, so I don't think this is a problem.When I use EEVEE's "Ray tracing", this problem will appear on models with skin shaders. This problem will not occur if it is not turned on. It should be turned on for better effects, not sure This "Ray tracing" is not a replaced version of "screen space reflection".
